# I am getting "cannot import name 'tensorflow_backend' from 'keras.backend'" when training a variational autoencoder

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, autoencoder

I cloned https://github.com/brunnergino/MIDI-VAE and am attempting to run it on my own MIDI data, but am running into this:

```
2020-07-08 11:58:35.839768: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/rodjm/PycharmProjects/MIDI-VAE/vae_training.py", line 17, in <module>
    import vae_definition
  File "C:\Users\rodjm\PycharmProjects\MIDI-VAE\vae_definition.py", line 6, in <module>
    from recurrentshop import *
  File "C:\Users\rodjm\PycharmProjects\MIDI-VAE\venv\lib\site-packages\recurrentshop\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .engine import *
  File "C:\Users\rodjm\PycharmProjects\MIDI-VAE\venv\lib\site-packages\recurrentshop\engine.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .backend import rnn, learning_phase_scope
  File "C:\Users\rodjm\PycharmProjects\MIDI-VAE\venv\lib\site-packages\recurrentshop\backend\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .tensorflow_backend import *
  File "C:\Users\rodjm\PycharmProjects\MIDI-VAE\venv\lib\site-packages\recurrentshop\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 1, in <module>
    from keras.backend import tensorflow_backend as K
ImportError: cannot import name 'tensorflow_backend' from 'keras.backend' (C:\Users\rodjm\PycharmProjects\MIDI-VAE\venv\lib\site-packages\keras\backend.py)
```

I have seen solutions which involve reinstalling tensorflow and keras, but this is not working.

Comment: @MZ I do not think that is true, I have used keras with tensorflow-gpu for years with no problems. Do you have evidence to back your statements?

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Dannng my b I'll back out. Thought switching to `tf.keras` was practical but I guess not.

Comment: @MZ its not practical to give generic advice, you don't know if this code will work with tf.keras, or if there will be other issues. People come here for answers and might take your comment as an absolute truth when it is not.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Is it not something worth trying for this issue though? It fixed my issues when I started using tensorflow-gpu.